# Join MySQL tables based on condition?

Tags: mysql, join, conditional-statements

**Problem:**

I'm trying to figure out how to join tables based on a condition in an SQL statement. I've spent an hour searching Google, SO, various websites and the MYSQL manual, but I just can't find the correct syntax for what I want to do.

I can't post the exact query I'm trying to get working, but I will post a simplified version for simplicity reasons.

**Scenario:**

Assuming I have three tables, `a` = person table, `b` = address table and `c` = car table.

Table `b` will always be joined to table `a`, becuase a person always lives at an address, but table `c` should only be joined to `a` if the value in the 'car_id' field is more than 0, because having a car is optional.

**The query:**

```
SELECT a.firstname, a.lastname, a.gender, a.address_id, b.address_firstline,  b_address_secondline, b.postcode, c.car_manufacturer, c.car_model 
FROM a 
INNER JOIN b ON b.id = a.address_id 
INNER JOIN c ON c.id = a.car_id AND a.car_id > 0 
WHERE a.id = 1
```

The query above will run fine for a person with the id of 1 because he owns a car. However, if the query is run for a person with the id of 2, the query will return 0 rows because she does not own a car.

How do I make this second JOIN optional? I've tried using the IF ELSE statement, but I'm forever getting syntax errors. Could someone point me in the right direction here? Thanks in advance

Comment: Have a look at [Left outer joins](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Left_outer_joins)

Comment: I will do, thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use left outer join to join c with a.

```
SELECT a.firstname, a.lastname, a.gender, a.address_id, b.address_firstline,  b_address_secondline, b.postcode, c.car_manufacturer, c.car_model 
FROM a 
INNER JOIN b ON b.id = a.address_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN c ON c.id = a.car_id AND a.car_id > 0 
WHERE a.id = 1
```

Comment: Works perfectly! I can't believe how much time I wasted on this. I will have to read up further on joins, as I obviously don't fully understand them yet.

Answer (score 3):

Use `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN` on table `c`.

*Unilateral* joins work on this scenario.

**A brief explanation.**

- `a INNER JOIN b ON a.field1 = b.field1` returns every row for which both `a.field1` and `b.field1` exist and are equal
- `a LEFT JOIN b ON a.field1 = b.field1` returns every row from table `a` and returns every row in table `b` for which `a.field1 = b.field1`, and `null` values for non-matching values on table `b`.
- `RIGHT JOIN` is analogous to `LEFT JOIN`

Comment: +1 for the explanation. I understand what's going on now, thanks :)